# Given 4 corner points of a rectangle in 3d space, how to find its "plane" equation?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Context:

> A BoundingPolytope defines a polyhedral bounding region using the intersection of four or more half spaces. The region defined by a BoundingPolytope is always convex and must be closed.
>   Each **plane** in the BoundingPolytope specifies a half-space defined by the equation:
>
> Ax + By + Cz + D <= 0

source: from a [javadoc](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/BoundingPolytope.html), this is for programming purpose

---

I need the value of A, B, C, and D for *a plane* as in that equation and all I have is corner points of a rectangle that lies in that plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need $3$ of these corner points.  Let these corner points be denoted $\vec{v_1}$, $\vec{v_2}$, and $\vec{v_3}$, treated as vectors from the origin to the point.

Then, the equation of your plane is:
$$\left((x, y, z)-\vec{v_1}\right) \cdot \left[(\vec{v_3}-\vec{v_1})\times(\vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1})\right] = 0$$

Where $\times$ is the cross product, $\cdot$ is the dot product, and $(x, y, z)$ are the free variables describing the plane.

Comment: A more straighforward method is to plug the coordinates of 3 of the points in the equation of the plane. You get a homogeneous system of 3 equations for the 4 unknowns $A,B,C,D$. This you can solve by say Gaussian elimination. Or, set $D=1$ (assuming the plane doesnt pass through the origin), then you get a inhomogenous system of 3 equations with 3 unkowns, which you can solve by Gaussian elimination, or by inverting the cooeficient matrix (if you do it on a computer, like in Mathematica, there are commands that invert matrices).

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem